# how to have string and image as a content of a button

Tags: android

I have a button in which I set its background a to 9 patch drawable and  I set the text to some value. All works well. Now I want to add an image with the text (so text and image inside the button).
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoter, how about you care to say why?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because you have not shown what you tried so far, and it seems that you have not tried to look for an answer before posting.

Comment: Umm well. I did search and didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use styles in your button layout xml. 
`style="@style/settingTextView"` 
This will turn your button to the buttons you see in the settings APP. Then you can add left and right images to your button. Using - 
`android:drawableRight="@drawable/some_image_right"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_image_left" android:text="@string/button_text"`